# My micro-service does not start and throws an error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices

I use springcloud+springboot+hibernate:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop overrides final method pendingTasks.()I
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:94) ~[netty-transport-4.0.37.Final.jar:4.0.37.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:64) ~[netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49) ~[netty-transport-4.0.37.Final.jar:4.0.37.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:68) ~[netty-transport-4.0.37.Final.jar:4.0.37.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:63) ~[netty-transport-4.0.37.Final.jar:4.0.37.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:54) ~[netty-transport-4.0.37.Final.jar:4.0.37.Final]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil.newEventLoopGroupInstance(NettyUtil.java:139) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyOptions.eventLoopGroup(NettyOptions.java:99) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.<init>(Connection.java:769) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1410) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:305) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:247) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.connect(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:100) ~[spring-cql-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:94) ~[spring-cql-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:103) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you have a mixed of net versions on your class path...

- netty-common-4.0.27.Final
- netty-transport-4.0.37.Final

This can be the cause of your problem.

Comment: thanks for your question, and this problem i had fixed,the reason is i import some unused dependecies

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can exclude netty from being included by either one of your dependencies. To do so you just need to add the following to the dependency from which you don't want to use the subdependencies:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```